# Disabling a button doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I got a button which I want to disable when this method is getting called:

```
- (void)disableSendButton
{
    NSLog(@"disableSendButton method");
    self.sendBtn.enabled = NO;
    //[self.sendBtn setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Header file property from the button: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sendBtn;` and I also synthesize it.

`disableSendButton method` gets printed out but the button stays enabled... This is something weird and I don't know how I can fix this. The ViewController is called sendViewController and somewhere else in my program I do this `[sendViewController.sendBtn setEnabled:NO];` and this works like expected. Other then that I don't enable or disable that button...

**EDIT:**

```
sendViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SendView"];
if(self.sendButtonIsEnabled == NO){
    //sendViewController.sendBtn.enabled = NO; // Doesn't work
    //[sendViewController.sendBtn setEnabled:NO]; // Doesn't work
    [sendViewController disableSendButton];
}
```

Comment: You can try to log your `self.sendBtn` to see if it is nil. Maybe you send this message before the view finished load.

Comment: have you connected the outlet to the actual button in the IB?

Comment: I've connected the button with storyboards

Comment: You can try this.    `sendBtn.enabled = NO;`

Comment: The button is nil, but I connected it with storyboards? Maybe its because the method gets called before the button is loaded? how could I fix this?

Comment: try this [button setEnabled:NO]; may me help

Comment: Look in my question, the comment line, I've already tried that.

Comment: from which method you call [self disableSendButton]; ?

Comment: According Above Coding First Time Enable And After It Become Disable.Am I Right?

Comment: I call this in my UIPageViewController, look at my edit.

Comment: Do u have any IBAction for this button?

Comment: yes I do have an ibaction for the button

Comment: Ok. Where is your button actually placed? In SendViewController's view or self.view?

Comment: Where in your code, are you calling this code you posted in EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Call The Method in ViewDidLoad....

```
self.sendBtn.enabled = NO;
```